# assign function to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

i want the whole function in `myAlert` variable.
I am able to achieve it,but there is a problem 
The expected output is

```
function () {P}
```

but i am getting

```
function () {_DateControlId}
```

Note:I dont want my function expression to be converted into string in order to achieve the result.

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MUsP2/11/)

Comment: Try `return _DateControlId ;` and use `alert(myAlert());`! [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MUsP2/15/)

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Variables can change. The value of `_DateControlId` might vary each time you run the function. The JS compiler wouldn't replace the variable with a string when it made the function. Why would getting a string representation of the function be any different? Even if it was, why would you expect `P` and not `"P"`?! And you can't `alert` a function without converting it to a string: `alert` only deals with strings!

Comment: why cant i get function () {P} as the output,if function () {_DateControlId} is possible why not that?

Answer (score 2):

Try returning variable and call it as function in alert `myAlert()`:

```js
var _DateControlId = "P";

var myAlert = function() {
  return _DateControlId;
};

alert(myAlert());
```

**Clarification of js parser:**

```
[step 0]
// All variables is assigned it's value.
// So _DateControlId now is same as string "P"
var _DateControlId = "P";

var myAlert = function() {
  return _DateControlId;
};

alert(myAlert());
```

---

```
[step 1]
// All variables are replaced with it's values.
// So _DateControlId is replaced with string "P" (as it's his value)
var myAlert = function() {
  return "P";
};

alert(myAlert());
```

---

```
[step 2]
// Functions are evaluated. So your anonymous function is evaluated value of _DateControlId.
var myAlert = "P";

alert(myAlert());
```

---

```
[step 3]

// variable are placed in alert function call. Alert function accepts only string parameters 
alert("P");
```

---

[step 4]
   // alert function is executed and you get pop-up that says "P" - value of myAlert function
   // that in turn is value of _DateControlId.

---

Now that you want to see `function () {P}` in your pop-up message, you need to pass it string.
So basically your code in the end must be as follows:

```js
    var _DateControlId = "P";
    var myAlert = function() {
      return "function () {" + _DateControlId + "}";
    }

    alert(myAlert());
```

Comment: Please check my question,my expected result is                        function () {P}  and not only P

Comment: @Anuj you mean `var fn = "function () {" + _DateControlId + "}"`?

Comment: No,i can only access the content within {} to achieve the result,i cannot make whole part to string

Comment: @Anuj Ok, let's get some clearance: you want to get **string** `function () {P}` as result of `alert(myAlert)` **OR** do you want to get **function that returns** `_DateControlId` value (that is equal to `P`) and that function must be as variable `myAlert`?

Comment: i want to get function () {P} as result of alert(myAlert) but not in string

Comment: @Anuj Alert can only print strings.

Comment: in 4th step u have done "function () {" + _DateControlId + "}" but i dont want whole thing to be stringified,i just want the part in { } to be used.please understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66744/discussion-between-justinas-and-anuj).